# Does the order of const, var, out parameters matter?

Tags: delphi, delphi-xe7

I'm refactoring a large procedure and now I'm getting lot's of small procedures, functions with lot's of parameters passed back and forth. And as I would like to keep same/similar performance and refactoring that is maintainable, I'm trying to understand what is best approach so I don't break the code.

This is most common how these new functions look:

```
function ProcessA(const ProjName,ProjPath:string; 
   ProjID:integer; 
   var ProjDest:string):string;

function ProcessB(const ProjName,ProjPath:string; 
   const ProjID,ProjHID,ProjGID:integer; 
   var ProjDest:string; 
   out ProjDelPath:string):string;
```

I read lots about const, var, out parameters. Should I order them first all const, then all normal, then var and last out...

**Does the order of them matter, at all?**

---

**EDIT:**

To clarify why the question or if someone uses the same this, I use IDE's *Refactor/Extract Method* feature that does a good job, but it makes no sense of parameters it puts in place. So, when I was reordering and changing parameter names, I saw the issue with no standard order of types of parameters.

Comment: The order does not matter in a simplistic way. But there are often reasons why you want certain parameters to appear first. You might want input parameters before output parameters, for instance. It's up to you.

Comment: Const and value parameters with default values must occur at the end of the parameter list. Otherwise you can do as you please.

Comment: @DavidHeffernan Yes, that was my idea, too, first input then mixed (var) and last out. I use _Refactor/Extract method_ to help me with this and I need to sort parameters every time, because it just mixes up input, output parameters, not good. So, I wanted to make sense and kind of a standardize it.

Comment: Order does matter to some degree, because it affects which parameters are passed using CPU registers and which are passed using the call stack instead.  Minor performance difference, but it might be important depending on the context of the call.

Comment: @RemyLebeau would you care to add some links on this topic, or maybe even add an answer for everybody reading this?

Comment: @MikeTorrettinni: that information is readily available if you search for it. Some information is in Embarcadero's documentation: [Calling Conventions](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/RADStudio/en/Procedures_and_Functions#Calling_Conventions)

Comment: @RemyLebeau Great, I'm sure others will find the link good resource, especially if they don't know what to search for, as I didn't.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The order of the kind of parameters doesn't matter, with one exception; Default parameters (like `fn(AFloat: single; AInt:integer = 0): integer;` ), which means you don't have to pass anything for `AInt` if you are happy with the default value. These params have to be at the end of the parameter list, and can be omitted only from the end.
You can read more about parameters [here](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/RADStudio/Seattle/en/Parameters_%28Delphi%29).

Comment: Great to point that out, will make sure I use this as designed!